# Using the serverless framework, how do I pass the name of a generated EventBridge rule to my lambda as an environment variable?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-event-bridge

I'm using the serverless framework and use `serverless.yml` to generate EventBridge events and rules that trigger my lambda functions.

One of these rules will be a scheduled event that I need to [disable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_DisableRule.html) in my lambda code under certain conditions. To do this I'll need the Rule name. I'd like to capture the generated rule name and pass that into my lambda as an environment variable. This is only known at runtime.

How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? It feels like you have not chosen the right tools to your problem. And you should have details of what triggered the lambda.